# Should we move to close old, abandoned questions with not enough detail?

Tags: discussion

By old, I mean about 30-45 days or older. By abandoned, I meant that people have asked for clarifications in the comments so that they can answer the question better but the OP hasn't responded in days. I was thinking of closing them under the not a real question justification.

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. For help clarifying this question so that it can be reopened, see the FAQ.

Shall I go through with it or should I leave those questions alone?

Answer (score 4):

I would absolutely go for it.

If the question is poor quality and the OP is clearly no longer interested in it, there is no reason for us to keep it open. The OP gains no benefit for it being open with no good answers; the site doesn't benefit by having open unanswerable questions.

If a different OP/answerer comes to the site, there is nothing to stop them opening a new  (and hopefully better) question which will hopefully attract better answers, so I can see no downside of closing abandoned low-quality questions.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking of questions without an answer, there is no need to close them, since they are automatically deleted:

- After a month, if the question score is negative and there is no answer
- After a year, if the question score is zero and there is no answer

As for closed questions, they are going to implement [an automatic deletion for questions that matches the following criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173513/turbocharging-the-roomba-solutions-for-premature-deletion/177675#177675):

- Closed more than 7 days ago
- Not closed as a duplicate
- Score <= 0
- Not locked
- No answers with a score > 0
- No accepted answer
- No pending reopen votes
- No edits to the body or title of the question in the past 7 days

As for closing questions, I would close those that are really bad questions. If the user who asked the question didn't reply to a comment asking for clarifications, but the possible answers are two, I would rather not close the question.